# When align the neutron's magnetic dipole moment, does moving neutron radiates?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, neutrons

Was performed an experiment in the past, where neutrons pass a magnetic field and their magnetic dipole moment get aligned? Was measured an electromagnetic radiation during the experiment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The neutron's magnetic moment is about $50\rm\,neV/T$, so a spin flip in a laboratory magnetic field corresponds to a sub-$\mu$eV photon.  I don't know that there is any technology for detecting single sub-$\mu$eV photons.

In practice, neutrons entering a magnetic field are equally likely to find themselves aligned or anti-aligned with the field.  Generally the neutrons are polarized by absorbing or reflecting one spin state more than the other, and the polarization is flipped by passing the neutron through a region of magnetic field oscillating at the resonant frequency (like NMR).