# Why only moving magnet relative to coil makes electric current and one that is stopped relative to coil don't make?

Tags: electricity, electromagnetic-induction

Can you explain using the fact that electric field and magnetic field are perpendicular each other?
I wanna visualize the field and electric current image in my head.

I searched this and read some answers, but it was about energy conservation. this kind of method of explanation is indirect explanation. I want direct explanation.

Also, the way that using formula is not explanation at all. formulas are just result, I want theoretical explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To explain why a changing magnetic field induces a current in a wire, it is of interest how an electron (many of them are the observable current) is influenced by a magnetic field.

It is an empirical fact that an electron is set in motion when a changing magnetic field is applied. In another experimental set-up, a moving electron is deflected sideways in the plane defined by the direction of the magnetic field and the direction of the moving electron (see the [Lorentz force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force)).

[image]

From both observations it is clear that a wire wound into a coil can best convert the kinetic energy of a moving magnet into electric current.

Now the explanation behind the explanation (on a more detailed level). For this one has to recognize that electric fields and magnetic fields not interact directly. So how is a charge with its electric field influenced by a magnetic field? The key is the magnetic field of the electrons. Yes, the electron has an intrinsic (under *any* circumstances existing) magnetic dipole.

In order to draw the full picture, one should also note that when an electron is deflected - which is an acceleration - it emits electromagnetic radiation (in the form of photons). An emission of photons in turn changes the speed and direction of the electron's movement.

A moving magnetic field with its changing magnetic field - from the electron's point of view - does three things to the electron:

- it tries to align the magnetic dipole of the electron with its one magnetic field
- causes the electron to emit photons that misalign the dipole again and
- deflects the electron in this way.

Please note that there is little interest in the mechanism behind the Lorentz force and the other induction processes, and this is a possible reason why you will receive downvotes. I think your question is a good question, and your statement "formulas are only result, I want a theoretical explanation" lets me answer you.

Comment: Once you get into the idea of deflecting magnetic moments, I think you are in non-peer-reviewed land? In particular, it sounds like if I align the magnetic moment of the electron with the magnetic field in advance, the electron would not satisfy your first bullet point as there would be nothing to align, therefore your approach would predict that the electron does not deflect, when in fact it does in standard electromagnetic theory. Also seems like the strength of the magnetic moment would have to play a role in the Lorentz force, so you'd get deflections of neutrons similar to protons, say.

Comment: @CR Drost What is your knowledge  here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/186744/when-align-the-neutrons-magnetic-dipole-moment-does-moving-neutron-radiates ?

Comment: To be a little more clear: I am not saying that you can't deflect a neutron with a magnetic field, although I suspect that it might have to be inhomogeneous and that a constant field can't do it. NMR does lots of magnetic stuff with neutrons I think. But it would not be the standard first-order consequence of the Lorentz force. There is an intriguing connection here where the force you are describing is apparently due to Larmor precession, so has a radius of curvature $2 m v/(q g B),$ compared to the standard $m v/(q B)$ Lorentz radius, but I think that connection is just dimensional analysis.

Comment: In particular while $g\approx -2$ for electrons and muons, and maybe I have the sign wrong, the $g$-factor for protons is +5.6 so if you set them in a magnetic field with a slow velocity, their magnetic moments will precess in circles that have nothing to do with the circles that the protons themselves are making.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that that's just the way it is.
All of physics is based on experimental results including Newton, the Maxwell equations, quantum mechanics - everything.

To visualize a permanent magnet's flux lines cutting a conducting loop there must be a gazillion illustrations of that on the web.  Either the coil or magnet has to move, or both.  Experimental fact!